# Merging a 2D array of intervals

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, linked-list, initialization, pass-by-reference

Below is code that takes a 2D array (a list of intervals) and merges them. Each interval is of size 2, but the list of intervals is of size `n`, e.g.

```
intervals = [[1,2], [2,4], [8,10]]
```

```java
public int[][] merge(int[][] intervals) {
    Arrays.sort(intervals, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]));
    LinkedList<int[]> mergedList = new LinkedList<int[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
        if (mergedList.size() == 0 || mergedList.getLast()[1] < intervals[i][0]) {
            mergedList.add(intervals[i]);
        } else {
            int max = Math.max(mergedList.getLast()[1], intervals[i][1]);
            mergedList.getLast()[1] = max;
            // mergedList.getLast() = new int[] { mergedList.getLast()[0], max };
        }
    }
    return mergedList.toArray(new int[mergedList.size()][]);
}
```

In the else statement, I originally tried the commented line but it gave me an unexpected type error. Why am I unable to replace the array within the mergedList BUT I'm able to replace the value within it? And when replacing the value, how do I know it's not just creating a copy and actually modifying the linked list?

Answer (score 0):

this line is the error

mergedList.getLast() = new int[] { mergedList.getLast()[0], max };

i think you wanted to write setLast in order to modify the last member of the list

mergedList.setLast()

Comment: yes! That line does cause an error and I'm trying to understand why the commented line creates an error but the line above it doesn't

Comment: because if you want to change the value of the last item in the list you can't use the getLast function. the getLast function return an item that you can use, but you can't change the value of the last item in the list by tryng to change the value with a get and a equals. if you want to change the value of the last item you have to use setLast.

Comment: That makes so much sense! This whole time I'm thinking it returns a value and I can override it, but getLast() returns the last so I can't override what the return is. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value to a function like you can to a variable!

```
a = 123     // works
a() = 123   // doesn't work
```

I'm guessing you want to overwrite the last item on the list. Since a `LinkedList` has no `setLast` method, you first have to determine the index of the last element and then overwrite it with `set(index, yourReplacingValueHere)`.Try this:

```
mergedList.set(mergedList.indexOf(mergedList.getLast()), yourReplacingValueHere)
```

Maybe that's an acceptable solution.